# Folder compression

Tags: compression

In Windows there is an option to compress the folders to save disk space. This is done by right clicking the folder and selecting the Properties and then pressing the Advanced button [Folder Properties Window](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2yhXU.png). 
The resulting compressed folder contains files which can be accessible in applications like MS Excel to reference. User don't need to decompress the files in that folder to access them. This saves space.

Can I get the same functionality in Ubuntu?

Comment: Which version of Ubuntu are you using?

Comment: https://linux.die.net/man/1/fuse-zip is one example; squashfs and fuse-bzip2 are others, but the latter two may be "read only": once you compress the files, you can't change them.